# Issue with Realm Notifications and UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

I currently have a Realm database with three objects:

```
class Language: Object {
      let lists = List<List>()
}

class List: Object {
      let words = List<Word>()
}

class Word: Object {
      dynamic var name : String = ""
}
```

So the object relation is: Language -> List -> Word

I display these objects in a UITableView, in a LanguageTableViewController, ListTableViewController and a WordTableViewController, respectively.
To update the TableView when changes occur, I use Realm Notifications in the LanguageTableViewController:

```
languageToken = languages.addNotificationBlock { [weak self] (changes: RealmCollectionChange) in
        self?.updateLanguages(changes: changes)
    }
```

With the current method to update the TableView (method is based on tutorials from the Realm site):

```
func updateLanguages<T>(changes: RealmCollectionChange<T>) {
    switch changes {
    case .initial:
        self.tableView.reloadData()

    case .update(_, let deletions, let insertions, let updates):
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: insertions.map {IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}, with: .automatic)
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: updates.map {IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}, with: .automatic)
        self.tableView.deleteRows(at: deletions.map {IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0)}, with: .automatic)
        self.tableView.endUpdates()

    default: break
    }
}
```

Now to my issue: This method works when new "Language" objects are added or updated. However, when a new List or Word object is created, this method is called too - with an insertion update. This leads to a UITableView Exception, because no Language objects were created, but the updateLanguages method wants to insert new cells.

My question is: How can I only monitor changes to the count/number of objects? Or is there a better approach to this issue?

Comment: Hmm, this sounds potentially like a bug in Realm. Logically, if the notification block is triggered because a child `List` object was added to a `Language` object, that notification block should only state that the `Language` object was updated with no insertions. When the notification block is being triggered, which row index is it saying was inserted?

Comment: This shouldn't happen. Please file a bug at https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/new with an Xcode project that Realm folks can run to reproduce and debug the issue. Thanks!